# Appending multiple elements to other elements jQuery JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have 7 paragraph elements with the class name `catalogue-description` that each has a paragraph sibling with the class name `redirect-link`.

I am trying to append the `redirect link` elements to the `catalogue-description`elements. The result should be that for each `catalogue-description`, there is one `redirect link` element as its child.

However, when I run my code, only 1 of the 7 `catalogue-description` will have all 7 `redirect link` elements appended to it, instead of one of each.

Here is my code:

**HTML**:

```
<p class="catalogue-description">LOREM IPSUM.</p>
<p class="redirect-link"> 
    HELLO
</p>
```

**jQuery**:

```
jQuery(".catalogue-description").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).append(jQuery(".redirect link"));
})
```

**Desired Result**:

```
    <p class="catalogue-description">
        LOREM IPSUM.
        <p class="redirect-link"> 
            HELLO
       </p>
    </p>

    <p class="catalogue-description">
        LOREM IPSUM.
        <p class="redirect-link"> 
            HELLO
       </p>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the `.redirect-link` that's the *sibling* of the current `.catalogue-description` that's being iterated over, else *all* `.redirect-link`s will be selected and appended to the current `.catalogue-description`. Use `.next()` to get the next sibling:

```
jQuery(".catalogue-description").each(function(){
    const $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.append($this.next());
})
```

```js
jQuery(".catalogue-description").each(function() {
  const $this = jQuery(this);
  $this.append($this.next());
})
```

```css
body > p {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="catalogue-description">LOREM IPSUM.</p>
<p class="redirect-link">
  HELLO
</p>
<p class="catalogue-description">LOREM IPSUM.</p>
<p class="redirect-link">
  HELLO
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".catalogue-description").each(function(){
   $(this).append('<p class="redirect-link">HELLO</p>');
})
```